# Google sheet ImportXML fails

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This one works:

```
=importxml("https://discgolfmetrix.com/?u=scorecard&ID=900113&view=result", "//table[@class='data data-hover']/tr/td[2]")
```

This one fails:

```
=importxml("https://discgolfmetrix.com/?u=scorecard&ID=1172639&view=result", "//table[@class='data data-hover']/tr/td[2]")
```

If it was the other way around I could understand it, since the first one has 2 tbody tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoogleSheets parses the page in its own way (parent >> child structure is not exactly the same as in your browser) . Use `//tr` in your XPath to circumvent parsing errors :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://discgolfmetrix.com/?u=scorecard&ID=1172639&view=result","//table[@class='data data-hover']//tr/td[2]")
```

Or use `IMPORTHMTL` and `QUERY` :

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://discgolfmetrix.com/?u=scorecard&ID=1172639&view=result","table",1),"select Col2 OFFSET 1")
```

Output :
[image: Golf]

`EDIT` : More details :

For the first link, the parsed HTML structure is the following one :

```
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td></td>
        <td>your_data</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td></td>
        <td>your_data</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

And your XPath works.

For the second link, there's a preceding `tbody` element which contains the `tr` elements. The structure is :

```
<table>
    <tbody>     
        <tr>    
            <td></td>
            <td>your_data</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td></td>
            <td>your_data</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And your XPath fails. That's why you have to use `//` or declare the `tbody` element in your expression :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://discgolfmetrix.com/?u=scorecard&ID=1172639&view=result","//table[@class='data data-hover']/tbody/tr/td[2]")
```

Comment: How do you figure out how GoogleSheets parses the page? Or is it just experience? :)

Comment: Experience, code reading and wild guess. :) I've added some details to my post.